# need help. all contacts shown anonymous even after user signups or login by email on my website

Tags: google-tag-manager, mautic

i have installed mautic on my php server subdomain and my website is based on ASP.NET so it is hosted on another server, i managed to install mautic tracking script which is available in the configuration > Tracking via google tag manager and it captures unique page views and users but all contacts shown are anonymous even after the user signups or login by email is there something i have to add in the tracking code so that it collects email from login or register forms , is it possible that google tag manager is blocking the tracking of email ?

Answer (score 0):

How are you having them provide the details, are you using a Mautic form or your own form and pushing the data over to Mautic? If using a Mautic form, have you connected up the fields in the form with the Mautic profile fields so that Mautic knows what to do with the data?

Do you see any console errors at all in your browser developer tools?

You should be fine using GTM to deploy your tracking code - if it's grabbing the visits then it should also pull the data through.